# How to bind data model in directive and set event handler correctly

Tags: angularjs

All:

Currently, what my directive code looks is pretty simple:

```
    <div ng-controller='main'>
        <dirtest></dirtest>
        <dirtest></dirtest>
    </div>

<script>
     var app = angular.module("vp", []);
        app.controller("main", function($scope){
            $scope.name="init name";
        })

        app.directive("dirtest", function($compile){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope: false,
                controller : function($scope){
                },
                compile: function(tEl, tAttrs){
                    return {
                        post: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl){
                            el.append($compile("<button class='dirbtn'>{{name}}</button>")(scope));
                            $("button.dirbtn").on("click", function(){
                                scope.name = Math.random();
                                console.log(scope.name);
                                scope.$apply();
                            });
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

**what this code supposed to do is**:  Click any button, change all the buttons text.

**First question:**
Rather than using $compile to compile hard coded scope data model {{name}}, is there a way that I can programmatically do the data binding to dynamically added DOM?

**Second question:**
When I added two dirtest directives to page, one wierd thing is the clicking on first button will **call its post link function twice**(we can tell from the console, there are two numbers generated when I clicked the first button) while the second one only once. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
     var app = angular.module("vp", []);
        app.controller("main", function($scope){
            $scope.name="init name";

            $scope.clickfunc = function(){
                $scope.name = Math.random();
                console.log($scope.name);
            });
        })

        app.directive("dirtest", function($compile){
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                scope: false,
                controller : function($scope){
                },
                compile: function(tEl, tAttrs){
                    return {
                        post: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl){
                            el.append($compile("<button class='dirbtn' ng-click='clickfunc()'>{{name}}</button>")(scope)); 
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks so much. Could you talk a little bit detail why my way lead to that twice calling? I am kinda confused...

Comment: Hmmm, to be honest, I saw your code, and I immediately focused on the way you were binding the event instead of using ng-click.
However I hadn't seen this issue you mentionned until you asked above.
Maybe because you use scope.$apply inside an event-bound method inside a $compile. But not sure at all.
Anyway, try to always do as simple as possible is my advice.

Comment: thanks for advice, I really learn a lot. The reason why I want to put the event handling in directive is because I want to make that directive more decoupled as an individual directive, I may put it in different controller scopes which as well has a $scope.name( such as there is another main2 controller). If I set that click handling in controller, that may not my design way.

Comment: Then, just create a controller in the directive and move the clickfunc inside this directive's controller, this way, it'll come with your directive and can be reused.